# How can i add an administrative build in jenkins?

Tags: bash, build, jenkins, configuration-management

i'm trying to figure out how can i add an administrative build to Jenkins that will manage a few builds, and how can i path the parameters from the administrative build to the child builds.

Comment: Did you try the suggestion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) is what you're looking for.

Once you've installed the plugin, refer 2nd snapshot below. Go to `Configure` page of your project. Search for `Build > Add build step > From drop-down menu, select Trigger/call builds on other projects`. After that, click on `Add Parameters > From drop-down menu, select Current build parameters`

[image]

Above snapshot is of parent job A where i am defining a string parameter, which will be utilized in its child job B.

[image]

Above snapshot is again of parent job A where i am specifying the downstream (child) job B and also enabling `Current build parameters`, *which will ensure that the parameters defined in parent job A are visible to child jobs*. Once we are done with these settings, we should be able to see the upstream job link in the child job B as shown below. This will confirm that things are fine till now. :)

[image]

Now the only task left is using/calling the variable (defined in parent job A) in child job B. This is shown in the below snapshot:

[image]

- I tested it on Windows so i used `%string%`.
- If you're on UNIX/Linux machine, select 'Execute shell' and use `${string}`

Comment: so all this steps i have to perform on my downstream build not on the upstream right?

Comment: No. You have to add this step in your upstream (parent) job only.

Comment: Let me know whether you're aware about how to add parameter in a job.

Comment: the thing is that the upstream job is set as Build Flow and it doesn't have this option. i have this option only in the downstreams..
I have this option in my upstream 
"post-build Action" -> Trigger parameterized build on other projects -> then i've entered in the "projects to build" my childstream" and chose current build parameters.
Is it the right way to do that?
After i've done this how can i access this parameter from the child stream that specified let's say the name of this parameter "VERSION_NUMBER" ?

Comment: Ok. I guess you do not have 'Parameterized Trigger Plugin' installed. Are you fine with installing the above plugin or do you want to try with the one you already have?

Comment: I just tried installing Build Flow plugin but i could not find 'Trigger parameterized build on other projects' in 'Add post-build action'. I suspect you already have installed 'Parameterized Trigger Plugin'. Just for testing purpose, i suggest you create a fresh project and make sure to select 'Build a free-style software project'. We can then move further to troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: actually it's installed "parameterized-trigger plugin is already installed." but the thing is that what you are telling me is true about the childstreams because the upstream is configured as a Build Flow, let's say that i've configured everythig as you said how can i access this parameter from the childstream or from one of the bash scripts that i'm running on the childstream? 
Is it going to like this $VERSION_NUMBER

Comment: If you have set up the "Trigger parameterized build on other projects" section as i described above and more importantly, `enabled` the 'Current build parameters' as shown in the snapshot above, then in the child build, $VERSION_NUMBER will print the version as long as you have defined the same variable (VERSION_NUMBER) in upstream job and assigned it a value (say some default value).

Comment: The thing is if i'm selecting 'Build a free-style software project' i don't have the Flow option which has inside the 'Define build flow using flow DSL' where i can type the flow of the childbuilds..
Maybe you are familiar with another way to configure this flow..

Comment: Yes, i can try but only after i know what type of flow do you need.

Comment: build("b")
build("c")
by the way i've passed this parameter (VERSION_NUMBER) form the upstream to the child stream but the child sctream hasn't recognized the value of this parameter

Comment: Your build-flow is straight-forward and can be easily implemented. Also, i tried a sample build after defining a variable and printing it in child job and it worked fine. Did you try your test on Build-Flow job?

Comment: yes i've created a Build-Flow job then i set up a parameterized String in this build, i called it VERSION_NUMBER and in the post-build Actions i added 'Triger parameterized build on other projects' and chose current build parameters -> then tried to access this parameter from one of my scripts that are running on downstream and it printed {env.VERSION_NUMBER} and not the value that i've entered. Maybe i need to configure anything else in the downstream?

Comment: I suggest you leave the Build-Flow plugin and use the 'Parameterized Trigger Plugin'. I use this plugin extensively in many of my builds and your DSL is very easy to configure. I have added few snapshots and i feel that might help you. Please create all jobs using 'Build a free-style software project'. Just follow the snapshots and you will be able to use the variable in your downstream job easily. :)

Comment: So, i've checked it, and defined a string parameter in job A and added a build step as you suggested, in the projects to build i wrote project B, but i can't see on the main page of project B the link to project A which should be the upstream, by the way i didn't understand where have you defined the link between this projects..
How jenkins should recognize that A is upstream?

Comment: Seems you have not read my _detailed_ answer above. :) I had clearly written after the second snapshot that _Above snapshot is again of parent job A where i am specifying the downstream (child) job B_. So unless you define the job name B in configuration page of job A, you will not be able to see the link to project A in project B.

Comment: So the thing is that i didn't understand where exactly i need to specify the downstream (child) job B.
I haven't found any field in job A that says set a downstream..

Comment: Have you installed `Parameterized Trigger Plugin`? If that is installed, _only_ then will you find the option in the dropdown of  `Build` section (shown in snapshot #2)

Comment: Yes, it's installed..
i'VE Added the Trigger/call Builds on other projects, i can see on Job A main screen:
Subprojects

Static

B(non-blocking)
but i can't see on my upstream which is A the childstream B as in the snapshot that you've attached..
By the way what i want to do finnaly with this is to build just job B without A so A will manage B and C

Comment: Thanks a lot it's working now!
Now I need to set more complicated job that will manage about 5 jobs with some conditions, is it possible to set it without DSL?

Comment: Yes, it is possible but i think it's beyond the scope of the original question that you raised. I would suggest you raise a new post for that along with all the details you need.

Comment: How can i add the properties of job B to job C from the Properties Content:
For example i've defined there some variable 'directory' that holds the directory name -  and i want to path it to job C.
I've added a post-build triger - > Trigger parameterized build on other projects - > entered Job C and chose current build parameters, but it's not passing the properties that i've defined in job B

Comment: Where exactly is `Properties Content`? In which section did you use it? I could not find it. I defined a _String Parameter_ in job B and used the same string parameter in job C and it worked.

Comment: Under Build Environment you have a checkbox "Inject environment variables to the build process" -> "Properties Content" where you can  define all the extended environment vatiables: for example home_directory where you'll store the path, and you can access it via the bash scripts or through any other method.
So my question is how can i path this properties from job B to job C .

Comment: I don't have the [EnvInject plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) installed but you can pass the dir name by simply using _Parameters from properties file_ option. This option is in the same dropdown where you selected _Current build parameters_. Create a file and put the variable and its value in the file, for ex., `dir=ABC`. Now specify the file location in the box _Use properties from file_. That's it. I have tested it and it works. I am able to see the value of dir in my child job C.

Comment: Is it a txt file or it should have some special extension like .properties?

Comment: It can be anything, even without an extension. Just make sure that you are specifying the full path.

Comment: It didn't work.
This is what i wrote in the file:
someVar=test1212
ravenDir=/net/TLV-RAVEN-BLD3/ccstore/builder/hudson/workspace/RavenApp1.5.5.0_Plat_Mig/builder_RavenApp1.5.5.0_Plat_Mig/vobs/ravenp/Raven/
This is how i tried to print it from the script:
echo testing ${someVar}
It didn't print the value of the var

Comment: It has to work unless you skipped some part of what i mentioned. Did you get the option _Parameters from properties file_ in the same dropdown where you selected _Current build parameters_ earlier? If yes, then did you specify the _correct absolute path_ to the properties file? If yes, then try baby steps: just put `dir=ABC` in the file and print the variable (`echo $dir`) in the **same job** and see whether you get ABC as output.

Comment: @user3502786: Did you try the suggestion?

Comment: Thanks it's working, I'm wondering if there is a way to path a content of a txt file as a parameter so my script will be able to use the string inside

Comment: I guess your new concern has already been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25350570/jenkins-how-can-i-upload-a-text-file-and-use-it-as-a-parameter), correct? :)

Comment: @user3502786: Request you to close this link if you feel it has been answered: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311133/jenkins-how-can-i-pass-parameters-from-the-upstream-to-downstream`. If it doesn't, then please let me know your concern.

Comment: I think that for now i found a solution, i'll build a small script that will cat the txt file into a variable and then i'll call my next script with this parameter.