# Jenkins - How can i pass parameters from the Upstream to Downstream

Tags: build, jenkins, build-process

I have 3 builds:
A -  is the Master build which control the flow
B- Anoter build 
C-  will be executed after B
I want to add a String parameter to A so the user will enter some String manually, and i'm not sure how can i path this parameter to B.
lets say that this is my build flow:

build("B")
build("C")
I don't know how can i path the parameter to B, should i do that from the build flow or from the B build configuration and how can i do that.

Thanks in advance
Alex

Comment: I just noticed that you have asked the same question before. Why are you creating duplicates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
build("B", B_parameter: params["A_parameter"])<br>
build("C")
```

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin

Comment: Build Flow Plugin seems obsolete, people recommend to use the Pipeline plugin nowadays: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284103/jenkins-build-flow-versus-workflow-pipeline-plugin

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is with the Parameterized Trigger plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin

This allows you to trigger another job using, but not limited to:

```
* a set of predefined properties 
* properties from a properties file read from the workspace of the triggering build
* the parameters of the current build
```

With Build A, B, and C you set th3m up as a parameterized builds (i.e. to ask for a value for a parameter).  This a setting near the start of the job config page.  For example to take a parameter you name `MY_ID`.  This is now accessible as $MY_ID in build A.

Now, when you build A an it prompts for MY_ID.  Then add a build step in Job A to trigger "B" with parameters, and pass it all the parameters of build A.  Now build B will also have the parameter $MY_ID that was set when you ran a build of A.

Comment: Should i write it in the Define build flow using flow DSL ?
If yes can you show me, now all i have there is :
build("B")
build("C")
and i just want to make sure i need to set up all the builds as parameterized and not only the root build which is 'A' in my case.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use DSL--I configure all my flows manually through the UI

Comment: so how can i configure the flow using the UI? i didn't find an option .. can you send me a snapshot?

Comment: To enable parameters on a project, in the configuration screen about the 4th option down is 'This build is parameterized'.  My screen shows: Project Name, Descripts, Discard Old builds, then a check box 'This build is parameterized'.  Check it, then you can add parameters.

Comment: lets say it was done on the upstream how can i pass this parameter to the childstream (downstream), because i know how to add parameters to jecnkins

Comment: Ok, install teh parameterized Trigger plugin.  After that in your section 'Build' section and 'Post Build Actions' you can add a 'Trigger/call  builds on other project'  and add parameters or set of parameters to pass to the downstream project.

Comment: i've done this when i'm running the scripts on the downstream using the name of upstream parameters $VERSION_NUMBER for example it doesn't  get the value in the script... any idea?

Comment: @user3502786  you have to set the downstream project to be parameterized as well, and specify a parameter named exactly after any defined in the parent that you want to use.  Is Project B configured build with parameters, one of which is named 'VERSION_NUMBER'?

Answer (score 2):

[Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) is what you're looking for. For details on how to pass parameter from master build to child build, check my answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25304076/how-can-i-add-an-administrative-build-in-jenkins/25304205#25304205) link.

Answer (score 1):

Wooooow, so after a couple hours of playing "Which plugin is missing from this equation?", it turned out that none of these answers worked due to a jenkins change called [SECURITY-170](https://jenkins.io/blog/2016/05/11/security-update/).

If you followed the steps in this answer and your parameters are not being forwarded, please go to this [other Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37263116/pre-defined-parameters-no-longer-passed-to-child-job) which provides the details of the issue. If you're feeling too lazy and just want to verify that SECURITY-170 is the crux of the issue, you can try this ***temporary*** solution, as it does not persist after reboot:

1. Manage Jenkins -> Manage Nodes -> Select your "Master", whatever it's named
2. Select the Script Console
3. Paste this in and hit the `Run` button: `System.setProperty("hudson.model.ParametersAction.keepUndefinedParameters", "true")`
4. Retry the build that wasn't forwarding parameters

If that worked for you, you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39803973/3543437) I assembled on another question, but I would advise you read both the question and the context of my answer before attempting it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my pipeline (Master Build A) scripts to pass parameters to child jobs (Child Build B)

```
build job: 'svn test', parameters: [string(name: 'srcpath', value: params["mainpath"]), string(name: 'revision', value: params["mainrevision"])]
```

I configure 
-- mainpath and mainrevision as pipeline jobs parameters, 
-- srcpath and revision as child jobs parameters

Answer (score 0):

try this method

```
def myparams = currentBuild.rawBuild.getAction(ParametersAction).getParameters()
build job: 'Downstream JOb', parameters: myparams, wait: true
```