# Jenkins Build Flow versus Workflow (Pipeline) plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-build-flow

I notice there are (at least) two orchestration options for Jenkins

- [Build Flow](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin)
- [Workflow](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin) - Now known as Pipeline

I found Build Flow first and implemented an orchestration job around that which seems to work OK for our needs. Are there any advantages to switching to Pipeline? My thoughts for switching to Pipeline are

- Pro - The project seems more active than Build Flow
- Con - The DSL seems much more complex

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pipeline / Workflow is based off concepts from the Build Flow plugin.  Based on the wiki notes here: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin it would seem like Pipeline is the future of Build Flow.  I know for a fact that Pipeline is considered a a core strategic initiative for Jenkins 2.0 by Cloudbees and will be a front and center initiative going forward.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+2.0

In short, I would move to Pipeline to be ahead of the curve.

Answer (score 4):

Build Flow is the predecessor of Pipeline.
Pipeline is more complex and more powerful (flexibility, features, integrations, etc).