# Pre-Defined parameters no longer passed to child job

Tags: jenkins

I upgraded Jenkins today from 1.618 to 2.3.  This included installing a whole bunch of plugins that it recommended (Mostly Pipeline plugins and their dependencies).

Since the upgrade, I get a new error (or, at least, a new unwanted behavior) any time a job kicks off another job.  Any values passed to the child as "Predefined parameters" are ignored unless the child job already has those keys defined.

Let me illustrate:  Let's say that I have a `parent` job and a `child` job.

`Parent` launches `child` through a "Trigger parameterized build on other projects" Post-build Action.  In the definition of that Post-build Action, under the "Predefined parameters", I have `FOO=BAR` defined.

In Jenkins 1.618, when `child` was triggered this way, it would have `FOO` set as a parameter, with a value of `BAR`.

But in 2.3, `FOO` is not set on that build of `child`.

If I modify `child` so that `FOO` is always a parameter of that job, it will then pick up the `FOO=BAR` set from `parent`.  This is an unacceptable work-around because we pass dozens of parameters this way, and defining them on both ends is too fragile and violates the "don't repeat yourself" principle.

I get the same results whether I'm triggering the child job through through the "Trigger parameterized build on other projects" Post-build Action or through a MultiJob Phase of a MultiJob project.

Is this an intended change?  Was it broken before, and we were just using it incorrectly?  Or is this a bug?

Comment: This sounds like it's related to the latest [Jenkins security update](https://jenkins.io/blog/2016/05/11/security-update/).

Comment: It sure does.  Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

According to Jenkins 2 [Security updates](https://jenkins.io/blog/2016/05/11/security-update/), you can bypass it by setting:

> hudson.model.ParametersAction.keepUndefinedParameters=true

To validate this workaround, go to Manage Jenkins -> Script Console, and run:

```
System.setProperty("hudson.model.ParametersAction.keepUndefinedParameters", "true")
```

To make it permanent, change Jenkins arguments as follow (and restart Jenkins afterwards):

On Windows edit **jenkins.xml** in Jenkins home directory, for example:

```
<arguments>
    -Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle
    -Dhudson.model.ParametersAction.keepUndefinedParameters=true 
    -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8080
</arguments>
```

For most of the Linux distributions, you can modify *JENKINS_ARGS* inside file:

**/etc/default/jenkins** (or jenkins-oc)

For CentOS, modify *JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS* inside file:

**/etc/sysconfig/jenkins** (or jenkins-oc)

Here's a list of reported plugins, that were affected by the issue, and has an open bug already:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins+affected+by+fix+for+SECURITY-170

Comment: How do you add `hudson.model.ParametersAction.keepUndefinedParameters=true` to the `linux` file **/etc/default/jenkins**? I tried add it with and without the `-D` at the start in the JENKINS_ARGS field. I can't seem to locate anyone notating how to do this either...

Comment: For some reason, on my Debian install, adding the option to JENKINS_ARGS didn't work; instead it worked when adding it to JAVA_ARGS

Comment: Append `JAVA_ARGS="$JAVA_ARGS -Dhudson.model.ParametersAction.keepUndefinedParameters=true"` to **/etc/default/jenkins** (on Ubuntu) and restart Jenkins from the command line `sudo service jenkins restart`.

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 solutions:

1. Command line:
   `java -Dhudson.model.ParametersAction.keepUndefinedParameters=true -jar jenkins.war`
2. Groovy code:
   `import jenkins.model.*; System.setProperty("hudson.model.ParametersAction.keepUndefinedParameters", "true")`

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find a Start-to-End answer on how to set this for a linux box. After a couple hours of cross-referencing guides, this is what ended up working. There are supposed to be a couple flavors of these Jenkins configurations. I'm using the Ubuntu flavor for this answer.

1. Get the [Groovy scripting](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin) plugin
2. Discern where your `$JENKINS_HOME` is being set. By default, it's supposed to be at `~/.jenkins`, but I didn't set this server up, so I had to go digging through some configuration files. In case you do too, this is what I had to do:

   - Check the contents of `/etc/default/jenkins` with `vi` to grab the value of `$JENKINS_HOME` -- mine was `/var/lib/$NAME` and further up the file, `$NAME` was set to `jenkins`, so it was `/etc/libs/jenkins`
3. Change directories to the `$JENKINS_HOME` path
4. Search for a directory called `init.groovy.d` -- if it doesn't exist, make one and then `cd` into it. You might have to use `sudo` if needing to make it
5. Create a new file in the `init.groovy.d` directory that ends in `.groovy` -- I just called mine `params.groovy`
6. Enter following script code into the groovy file we just made:

   - > `import jenkins.model.*;`
     >   `System.setProperty("hudson.model.ParametersAction.keepUndefinedParameters", "true")`

Save and Close, then reboot your Jenkins server.

That should unblock you, if you ran into the *same* problem I did. Your mileage may vary :) I ultimately used a start-up script to utilize that functionality in conjunction with [this solution proposed by Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Post-initialization+script).