# Reuse same parameters for multiple jobs in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I need to reuse the parameters for particular job(current), where the parameters were assigned  in the previous jobs itself.

- Is there any ways to proceed with this?

Eg:

```
Job 1:(build) 
    param A
    param B
```

Note: i have added the job2(test) by using "AddPostAction"

```
Job 2:(test)
    param A //value assigned in job1 
    param B
```

Answer (score 2):

[Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) is what you're looking for. For details on how to pass parameter from master build to child build, check my answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25304076/how-can-i-add-an-administrative-build-in-jenkins/25304205#25304205) link.